# "Function is not defined" onClick function inline of a component in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have create come component in reactJs, consist of 2 button which handle each onClick function,
But when I run the code "myfunction is not defined" error is appear.
I want to redirect page to specified address when button triggered.
Whats wrong with my code?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class MainMenu extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.slotClick = this.slotClick.bind(this);
    this.freqClick = this.freqClick.bind(this);
  }
   slotClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();    
  }
   freqClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>   
        <input type="button" value="By Time Slot" onClick={ slotClick } />
        <input type="button" value="By Frequency" onClick={ freqClick } />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default MainMenu;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to access the functions from `this`. And also you don't need to `bind()` because the functions are Arrow Functions.

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>   
        <input type="button" value="By Time Slot" onClick={ this.slotClick } />
        <input type="button" value="By Frequency" onClick={ this.freqClick } />
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `this` inside a `class component`.

when we use `arrow function` we doesn't need to bind the function

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class MainMenu extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
   slotClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();    
  }
   freqClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>   
        <input type="button" value="By Time Slot" onClick={this.slotClick()} />
        <input type="button" value="By Frequency" onClick={this.freqClick()} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default MainMenu;
```

Comment: Thanks Seraj, for you information when we use arrow function we doesnt need to bind the function..